# Pausing a video on Windows with Win32/COM

Tags: windows, winapi, com

Is there a way to pause the currently running media - like, the media that displays on the windows lock screen?

[image: Windows lock screen]

I wish to programmatically achieve the same thing as clicking that pause button in that image in the bottom right (except when the machine is not locked). What COM interface could I use to do this? They are very confusing to look through and there seems to be at least a couple related to media on Windows.

Comment: GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager

Comment: Thank you so much! I wouldn't have found it on my own. I'm a big fan of yours BTW!

Is there a COM interface for this, or is COM sort of out the window now in favour of WinRT?

Comment: The low level interface to WinRT is COM.